# Org Mode Python block evaluation cannot print result in the shell session

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, python, elpy

I have a python source block in org mode as below

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :session
  print('hello world')
#+END_SRC
```

and I have a *Python* shell already run, so when i press `C-c C-c`, the code gets evaluated by the *Python* shell. Below is what I have in the *Python* shell:

```
In [12]: print('hello world')
hello world

In [13]: open('/var/folders/y1/197_jjzs1yv2qz0m26z1jkxw0000gn/T/babel- 
2T9E0c/python-zCCqcO', 'w').write(str(_))

In [13]: 
Out[13]: 20

'org_babel_python_eoe'
In [14]: 
In [14]: 
In [14]: Out[14]: 'org_babel_python_eoe'
```

why there are so many extra lines output? and how can I avoid them?

I am using spacemacs with emacs v26.1 with elpy on a Macbook.